# TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined [react-native-payments]

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

i will try to make payment using Android-Pay.
for android-pay require following object.

```
global.PaymentRequest = require('react-native-payments').PaymentRequest;
const METHOD_DATA = [
{
    supportedMethods: ['android-pay'],
    data: {
        supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard', 'amex'],
        currencyCode: 'USD',
        environment: 'TEST', // defaults to production
        paymentMethodTokenizationParameters: {
            tokenizationType: 'NETWORK_TOKEN',
            parameters: {
                publicKey: 'BLGm3OTNgH8PJaHJBDLQ4Bpvi3aBW0U07c0W9lOCmnytX1YLQ56k31BsT7xaEPn0j3ZiN96pVooSVQ21VzuXLP4='

            }
        }
    }
}];

const DETAILS = {
id: 'basic-example',
displayItems: [
    {
        label: 'Movie Ticket',
        amount: {currency: 'USD', value: '15.00'}
    }
],
total: {
    label: 'Merchant Name',
    amount: {currency: 'USD', value: '15.00'}
}
};
const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(METHOD_DATA, DETAILS);
```

and then on button press called::

```
paymentRequest.show();
```

for generating publicKey using following ref: 
    #!/bin/bash

```
# Generate key.pem file:
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem

# Print public and private key in hex form:
openssl ec -in key.pem -text -noout

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -in key.pem -nocrypt

#!/bin/bash

KEY="04:a9:9b:54:81:b0:67:0d:d3:50:84:e0:d4:d2:29:
a5:3a:d6:5c:21:ae:5e:dd:58:75:f0:27:63:44:e8:
a9:86:8d:cf:17:64:63:96:54:34:ed:16:37:c4:37:
e6:b7:27:ad:06:af:b0:07:d1:b5:66:0a:2a:85:c0:
71:9e:cc:39:54"

echo $KEY | xxd -r -p | base64
```

Public Key: 
BKmbVIGwZw3TUITg1NIppTrWXCGuXt1YdfAnY0ToqYaNzxdkY5ZUNO0WN8Q35rcnrQavsAfRtWYKKoXAcZ7MOVQ=

Getting Error like:

```
 YellowBox.js:80 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

Comment: DO conditional check before accessing show method. Do it like if(paymentRequest){ paymentRequest.show();}

Comment: in the react-native-payment plugin, i did't find any documentation for publicKey: 'your-pubic-key'. how can i generate publicKey i will followed method is right or wrong i don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue in publicKey:
Generate PublicKey using following command and solve issue for me.

```
openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -text -noout 2> /dev/null | grep "pub:" -A5 | sed 1d | xxd -r -p | base64 | paste -sd "\0" -
```